# api request duplicated while using Rx java

Tags: android, generics, rx-java

first i am still new to RX java but i learned that Single.create emit only one observable and that's what happen but the problem is that the function itself executed twice so that how i make my request

```
    @Override
public Single<BaseResponse<D>> call() {


    Single<BaseResponse<D>> singleResponse = Single.create(emitter -> {
        Log.e("api request", "calling api request");
        request().getAsOkHttpResponseAndParsed(typeToken(), new OkHttpResponseAndParsedRequestListener<BaseData<D>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response okHttpResponse, BaseData<D> response) {
                try {
                    BaseResponse<D> r = new BaseResponse<D>(okHttpResponse) {
                    };
                    r.setData(response.getData());
                    r.setStatus(response.getStatus());

                    emitter.onSuccess(r);
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("error", "throwable");

                    emitter.onError(throwable);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ANError anError) {
                Log.e("error", "error");
                emitter.onError(anError);
            }
        });
    });

    singleResponse.doOnSubscribe(__ ->
            EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource.increment()).
            doFinally(EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource::decrement).subscribe();

    return singleResponse;
}
```

as a result of that function i get only one result(observale) so iam sure that the function itself calling only one time but all inside emitter -> { here } is calling twice and the backend informed me that he getting the request twice from me and i double check on that and found that line `Log.e("api request", "calling api request");` is calling twice

i implement same function but without rxjava and found that the request is called only one time

```
try {
        request().getAsOkHttpResponseAndParsed(typeToken(), new OkHttpResponseAndParsedRequestListener<BaseData<D>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response okHttpResponse, BaseData<D> response) {
                try {
                    BaseResponse<D> r = new BaseResponse<D>(okHttpResponse) {
                    };
                    r.setData(response.getData());
                    r.setStatus(response.getStatus());

//                    emitter.onSuccess(r);
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("error", "throwable");

//                    emitter.onError(throwable);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ANError anError) {
                Log.e("error", "error");
//                emitter.onError(anError);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: why this ? *singleResponse.doOnSubscribe(__ ->
            EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource.increment()).
            doFinally(EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource::decrement).subscribe();* ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're subscribing twice to the observable `singleResponse`.

I suggest you to try this code (just remove the first subscription) :

```
    @Override
public Single<BaseResponse<D>> call() {


    Single<BaseResponse<D>> singleResponse = Single.create(emitter -> {
        Log.e("api request", "calling api request");
        request().getAsOkHttpResponseAndParsed(typeToken(), new OkHttpResponseAndParsedRequestListener<BaseData<D>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response okHttpResponse, BaseData<D> response) {
                try {
                    BaseResponse<D> r = new BaseResponse<D>(okHttpResponse) {
                    };
                    r.setData(response.getData());
                    r.setStatus(response.getStatus());

                    emitter.onSuccess(r);
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("error", "throwable");

                    emitter.onError(throwable);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ANError anError) {
                Log.e("error", "error");
                emitter.onError(anError);
            }
        });
    });

    return singleResponse.doOnSubscribe(__ ->
            EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource.increment()).
            doFinally(EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource::decrement);
}
```